# Why is Spring calling a custom init method?

Tags: java, spring

I have a very confusing problem - for some reason, Spring's bean creation process is attempting to call a custom init method on one of my beans and throwing an IllegalArgumentException error, even though I haven't declared an init method on the bean, nor do I want one.

This is within a Spring Boot/Batch application. I've used @SpringBootApplication and @EnableBatchProcessing, and my batch configuration is using additional @Configuration classes to hold the configuration of individual steps.

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyBatchJobConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  private MyStepConfig myStep;

//Construction of other steps and the overall job (using the factories)

  @Bean
  public Step myStep() {
  //Step configuration, with the various readers, writers, etc
  //accessible through myStep (e.g. myStep.writer() )
  }
}

@Configuration
public class MyStepConfig {
  @Value("${myStep.propFoo}")
  private String foo;
  @Value("${myStep.propBazzle}")
  private String bazzle;
  private final String SOME_CONSTANT = "Constant Bar";

  //MyItemWriter is a Spring Batch ItemWriterAdapter<T> implementation
  @Bean
  public MyItemWriter writer1() {
    return new MyItemWriter(foo, SOME_CONSTANT);
  }
  @Bean
  public MyItemWriter writer2() {
    return new MyItemWriter(bazzle, SOME_CONSTANT);
  }
}
```

All of this is well and good, and seems much like many of the examples I've seen. Nothing unusual, I thought. And it compiles cleanly, but when I try to run it....

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'writer1' defined in class path resource [MyStepConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ...
...//stack trace omitted here
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:143) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.adapter.AbstractMethodInvokingDelegator.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMethodInvokingDelegator.java:135) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

So what are my eyes missing?

Edit: Here's MyItemWriter's constructor:

```
public class MyItemWriter extends ItemWriterAdapter<DataPOJO> {
  private String m1;
  private String m2;

  public MyItemWriter(String one, String two) {
    super();
    //Obviously, these aren't the actual messages, but the important things
    //are that they're not the default message of the requireNotNull message,
    //they're different from each other,
    //and neither is output in the stack trace.
    Objects.requireNonNull(one, "Without One MyItemWriter will not work.");
    Objects.requireNonNull(two, "Without Two, MyItemWriter will misbehave.");
    this.m1 = one;
    this.m2 = two;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends DataPOJO> items) throws Exception {
    //The remaining code of MyItemWriter, which does not call super(),
    //or, frankly, *any* of it's ancestors' methods.
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `MyItemWriter` about? Add a minimum of its code.

Comment: Eh. I hadn't really been worrying about, as the code fails before it even enters MyItemWriter's constructor. But sure, I'll add MyItemWriter's constructor.

Comment: It isn't failing on entering the constructor, that part has already been passed if you see this exception. The exception is telling you what is wrong. You are extending a class, which you probably don't understand, which requires some objects/parameters to be set to function appropriately. You aren't setting those properties and hence the validation rules (apparently applied in the `afterPropertiesSet` method of the `AbstractMethodInvokingDelegator` are triggered.

Comment: ItemWriterAdapter (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/adapter/ItemWriterAdapter.html) extends AMID. Neither AMID nor IWA have anything other than a default constructor. And MyItemWriter overrides ItemWriterAdapter's write() method which *should* completely ignore the default method, which *does* call AMID.

Comment: AMID has setters. The afterPropertiesSet method checks that the setters have been called to initialize the bean. Since you don't call the setters, the bean is not in a correct state when afterPropertiesSet is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all in the comments. You all got me looking it the right place.

The problem was (as you all probably guessed) that I had extended ItemWriterAdapter, when I should have implemented ItemWriter. And then I got blinded by existing code blinkers. Anyway, it's all sorted now.

And for future readers - ItemWriterAdapter is not a pre-implemented ItemWriter (note that it is NOT in a *.support package). It is what it says on the tin - an implementation of the Adapter design pattern, and should be used when the items you're iterating over in the batch job can handle their own write action. Generally, you'll probably just want to implement the ItemWriter interface directly.

Again, thanks all for helping straighten me out.